# Compile time error while running multiple c files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

**#Edited**

I am tested on simple two files now that are add.h and add.c.

I made a Makefile in order to compile my program. Here is my makefile.

```
# Make file for running the project
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -include
OBJFILES = add.o
LIB = add.h
TARGET = add

all: ${TARGET}

%.o: %.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<

${TARGET}: ${OBJFILES}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o ${TARGET} ${OBJFILES}

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

when I run

```
make add
```

I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -g -c -o add.o add.c
gcc -Wall -g -o add add.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_b", referenced from:
      _main in add.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [add] Error 1
```

here are snippets of my code

**add.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "add.h"

int main(void) {
    int a = 10, b=20;
    add(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

**add.h**

```
#ifndef __ADD_H_
#define __ADD_H_

extern int a,b;

int add(a,b)
{
    return a+b;
}

#endif // __ADD_H_
```

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile` but do read the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and try `make -p`; also read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: 1) Don't write this much code before testing it. 2) Do you give things names with leading underscores (e.g. `_com_task`)? **Don't.** 3) Read the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  will have a look at the sources you provided. Thanks

Comment: Read also [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and perhaps [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf), the C11 standard. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and learn to use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/); there is no reason to have 3 header files in your case. Look for inspiration on some programs on [github](http://github.com/)

Comment: @Beta actually yes, I have given all my functions name starting or including _com_tasks. Do you think that can be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `extern` keyword, losing track of your variables and making your code too complicated.

Let's try something very simple:

```
int main(void) {
  int a = 10; b=20;

  return 0;
}
```

This fails. The compiler complains about the statement `b=20;`, since it has never heard of this `b`. The semicolon that made this a separate statement was either a typo or a conceptual error caused by declaring `extern int b` elsewhere. *There is no need for `extern` here, at least not yet.*

This:

```
int main(void) {
  int a=10, b=20;

  return 0;
}
```

works.

Now for an `add` function.

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}

int main(void) {
  int a = 10, b=20;

  add(a,b);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the `a` and `b` in `add` are not the same variables as the `a` and `b` in `main`. This is crucial; do not proceed until you understand it.

Now add a *declaration* of the `add` function:

```
int add(int a, int b);  // <- declaration

int add(int a, int b)   // <- definition
{
  return a+b;
}
```

The *declaration* can be moved into a header file (`add.h`); the *definition* belongs in a source file (`add.c`).

Finally, I would advise you to add a line to the makefile:

```
add.o: add.h
```

Comment: waoooo they way you explained it cleared all my problems. I have read blogs but your explanation answered all my questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking a rule to actually build your object files. Right now you only have one to link them all together once they already exist. Try adding:

```
%.o: %.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

This tells make how to build object files out of source files.

Comment: I have tried adding and compiling it but it's still showing the same error.

Comment: You seem to be using `_com_task` in multiple functions, but you never defined it anywhere. Is there an implementation in any of the source files?

Comment: com_task is a struct variable and I have used it only in stack.h and nowhere else. do I need to provide my whole source code here?

Comment: I have compiled the program on the simplest version as you can see in the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing an `#endif` at the end of the last header file `queue.h` ?
This can be for sure an issue when compiling. Moreover, aren't you missing the `main_application.h` header file you are then including within the `stack.h` one for example?

Have a look at this: https://medium.com/@m.muizzsuddin_25037/error-ld-symbol-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-a5e5b648ffc seems helpful here and point our attention to the header files again!..

Comment: queue.h is having #endif

Comment: Ok @owais, I was pretty sure of this, thus just add it editing your code snippet here above ;)

Comment: I thought I might have done some mistake in declaring the headers

Comment: What @tsroe is saying is for definitely right!..

About the "mistake in declaring the headers" I was wondering if the `main_application.c` file should instead have been named `main_application.h` or is it just a typo? If not you need anyway an header file there!

Comment: Actually I have created a main_application.h  just to define the variables that are used in other files such as queue and stack. I tried the solution provided by @tsroe but it's not working as well.